# Small town election problem

Tags: probability

There exists a small town of 101 people in which John and Richard are running for mayor. Each person in the town (including the two running) cast their vote based on the toss of a fair coin. As the ballots are counted the results are reported vote by vote. The final result is 51 votes for Richard and 50 for John. What is the probability that as the votes were being counted Richard was always ahead?

Comment: Solution is given here : http://mathproblems.info/?page_id=765#s124 . But how are number of paths from (1,1) to (101,1) are calculated?

Comment: Moving from (1,1) to (101,1) means that the next 100 votes are equally split so that the lead stays at 1. And so any 50 of the next 100 votes are for the first candidate: ${100  \choose 50}.$